# How can get files from inner folder of storage in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I need to list files from storage->app->public->huetten->it contains 17 folders. Each folder contains images. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        if(!empty($id)) {
            $directories = Storage::disk('public')->allDirectories('huetten');
            foreach ($directories as $directory) {
                //dd($directory); // Here i get huetten/folder1

                $files = Storage::files($directory);
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    dd($file); // But here files are not listing
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to convert file to image format in laravel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storage uses the default Filesystem disk in `config/filesystems.php` which is set to `local` (*i.e* `storage/app/`) in a fresh Laravel project.

I assume that it is set to this same value in your project.

You want to list files in storage/app/public, and this corresponds to the public disk in `config/filesystems.php`.

In your loop, you can correctly the search directory by *getting a Filesystem instance that for the public disk* like you already do when listing the directories.

```
$files = Storage::disk('public')->files($directory);
/* [ 'storage/app/public/huetten/folder1/foo', 'storage/app/public/huetten/folder1/bar', ...] */
```

Comment: Thank you. After adding `disk('public')` I faced another issue. But that is related to folder permission. I enabled the permission and it works fine now.